# Can I create a custom implict type cast?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a class declared as such:

```
public abstract class CrmAttribute <T> : ICrmAttribute
{

}
```

And in one of the methods further down I have this

```
castedValue = (T)value;
```

`castedValue` is then used in other methods of type `T` as a parameter.

My problem is a case has come up such that the above cast throws an `InvalidCastException`.

From what I can tell this is one specific case; In Dynamics 2011 Microsoft finally moved away from custom types like `CRMNumber` and moved to inherent .Net types but not for all cases. Of the ones that remain, is a complex `Money` type that has one property of `.Value` which contains a decimal. This is where my Exception is thrown as I cannot cast a decimal to a Money type. Even though a `Money` object is essentially a `Decimal`.

I'm still fairly new to generics and much of this is inherited code so I'm well aware the *correct* response is to not do this per se, But all I want to do is to be able to create my own implicit cast of type `Money` to `Decimal` so that the line using `T` will cast correctly.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to add code to your class around the cast to test if T is the problematic type and perform the appropriate conversion instead of relying on cast.

Perhaps something like this:

```
if (typeof(Money).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
{
    // special handling required to convert decimal to money
    castedValue = new Money() { Value = value };  // ? best guess
}
else
{
    castedValue =(T)value;
}
```

Comment: I did try something like this but it wouldn't compile on the line `if(T is Money)` the error being `'T' is a 'type parameter' but is used like a 'variable'` and I wasn't sure how to circumnavigate this as I'm still clueing myself up on generics.

Comment: `T` is a type parameter, and so you cannot use an instance operator on it like `is`. For the same reason, you cannot write `DateTime is object` - it doesn't make any sense. The way to compare two types is by using the `Type` class that represents them. You can an instance of the `Type` class by either using `typeof(T)` or `myInstanceOfT.GetType()`. The former is for compile-time known types (such as with generics) while the latter is for run-time known types. So just use `if (typeof(T) == typeof(Money))`.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek careful: If `Money` is unsealed, and the object might be an instance of the derived class, testing for type equality will not work.

Comment: Updated pseudocode to use typeof().IsAssignableFrom() instead of IS

Comment: The comment about unsealed types seems wrong to me. If T is derived from Money, you cannot assign a reference to a plain Money object to T. If T is a base class of Money, you don't want any special behaviour (considering that object is a base class of Money). So it really should be a check for type equality.

Comment: The developer will have to use his own judgement about whether descendents need to be considered or whether simple type identity is sufficient. It's not our job to write his code for him. Our job is to advise him of options and limitations he might not be aware of.

Comment: @dthorpe and everyone else in the comment thread your input has been a great help. I've gone with `typeof` as neither will ever be a derived class ( if i understood that part correctly ) so a type identity should be more than enough. Thanks once again!

Comment: @phoog: If `Money` is unsealed, then it will be a breaking change in that API. Breaking changes, by definition, break you code. It is as likely to happen as the class being renamed to `Moola`, also a breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

It should be desired behavior that you cannot cast a decimal to a money type, due to the existance of multiple different currencies.

You cannot add an implicit cast to another type, unless it's declared in the type itself. You will have to do some explicit casting.

Comment: I realise it's not desired behaviour, but at the stage of the application it's built in the value is the important part. I would do explicit casting but as with the other answer, I'm unsure how to especially as other methods later on take `castedValue` as type T and when explicitly cast away from T to `Money` I get errors once more.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do the following:

```
public partial class Money
{
    public static implicit operator Money(decimal d)
    {
    // do whatever code in here you want to change your decimal into the money type
    }
}
```

I'm not claiming this is a good idea, but if Money isn't a value type and isn't sealed this should be possible.

Comment: A partial class enables a class definition to span multiple source files, not multiple assemblies. You cannot extend a class in such a way unless you have all parts of the partial class in a single project, which he doesn’t since `Money` is a Microsoft-supplied class.